# Pandas: ValueError iterating using `at`

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to update an empty pandas row with values from it's other columns.
If the `Fill_of` column has a `''` it should be like `sitecode_ART_0000` else `sitecode_ART_0000_0000` the '0000' come from the `Context` and `Fill_of` columns.

So far I create a column filled with `''` values.

I iterate through the dataframe setting the ifor_val, if however the `Fill_of` column = `''` then ifor_val is different, see below:

with this I get `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Any ideas where I've gone wrong? I think I need to include `.item()` somewhere.

```
gdf_objects['archaeologyid'] = ''

for i, row in gdf_objects.iterrows():
    ifor_val = sitecode_gbl + '_ART_' + gdf_objects['Context'].str.zfill(4) + '_' + gdf_objects['Fill_of'].str.zfill(4)
    if gdf_objects['Fill_of'] == '':
        ifor_val = sitecode_gbl + '_ART_' + gdf_objects['Context'].str.zfill(4)
    gdf_objects.at[i, 'archaeologicalid'] = ifor_val
```

Comment: One question, what is `sitecode_gbl` ? Some string?

Comment: yes, a string sorry

Comment: Ok, this string is changed in loop? Or is static?

Comment: Or it is from some column?

Comment: its a static string `1C19FLMTT` just a reference code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead your code use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), here looping is not necessary:

```
mask = gdf_objects['Fill_of'] != ''

ifor_val1 = '_' + gdf_objects['Fill_of'].str.zfill(4)
ifor_val2 = sitecode_gbl + '_ART_' + gdf_objects['Context'].str.zfill(4)

gdf_objects['archaeologicalid'] = np.where(mask, ifor_val2 + ifor_val1, ifor_val2)
```

Or:

```
mask = gdf_objects['Fill_of'] == ''

ifor_val1 = '_' + gdf_objects['Fill_of'].str.zfill(4)
ifor_val2 = sitecode_gbl + '_ART_' + gdf_objects['Context'].str.zfill(4)

#swapped values  - ifor_val2, ifor_val2 + ifor_val1
gdf_objects['archaeologicalid'] = np.where(mask, ifor_val2, ifor_val2 + ifor_val1)
```

Comment: what is `mask` doing in this as it is not in the code beyond?
This gives error `ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given`

Comment: @SpatialDigger - Use `gdf_objects['archaeologicalid'] = np.where(mask, ifor_val2, ifor_val2 + ifor_val1)`, if still not working if possible add some data sample? I think few rows with DataFrame for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: edit to `mask = gdf_objects['Fill_of'] != ''` and I'll accept the answer, thanks

Comment: @SpatialDigger - added both solutions ;)